# swift how to change custom mkannotationview dynamically

Tags: swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

tapping two buttons, I fill two different arrays of MKAnnotation based upon my own structs(from json objects).

I need to change the color or image of the annotations of one of these array based upon a value (data_speed).

is it possible? I only found differentiations if using mkuserlokation

```
var myLocationsToUse = [MKAnnotation]()
var towersArray = [TowersDataModel]()
var towersLocations = [MKAnnotation]()



    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customanotation")
//        annotationView.backgroundColor = Constants.skyBlue3Color
//        annotationView.contentScaleFactor = 0.5
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "ante3")
        annotationView.layer.cornerRadius = annotationView.frame.width / 2
        annotationView.layer.contentsScale = 0.3
        annotationView.layer.rasterizationScale = 0.3
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true //shows buble



        self.tappedAnnotation = annotation.title!!
        let infoAnnotationButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        infoAnnotationButton.frame.size.width = 44
        infoAnnotationButton.frame.size.height = 44
        infoAnnotationButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        infoAnnotationButton.setTitle("Info", for: .normal)
        infoAnnotationButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.annotationButtonCallout), for: .touchUpInside)
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = infoAnnotationButton






        return annotationView


    }
```

filling by:

```
    //grabs data from the sessions
    func getJsonReadings(URLToUse: String, session: String, completion: @escaping ([PostBlueprint]) -> ()) {

        //remember you need session_id

        //stringa del sito
        let jsonUrlString = URLToUse + session

        //verifichiamo che la stringa funzioni
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
            print("WARNING: url related error")
            return}

        //iniziamo la sessione //non è sul main thread
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            //vediamo che ci siano dei dati in "data"
            guard let data = data else {return}

            //check data structure before going ahead:
            let dataAsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            //commented due to high resurces usage on mac itself, use only for debug:
//            print("we found READINGS:\n" + dataAsString!)

            do {

                let dataStructs =  try JSONDecoder().decode([PostBlueprint].self, from: data)
                completion(dataStructs)
                for (index, singleStruct) in dataStructs.enumerated() {

                    if let myLat = singleStruct.lat, let myLong = singleStruct.long {

                        let locationToShow = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: myLat.SCConvertStringToDouble(),
                                                                    longitude: myLong.SCConvertStringToDouble()
                        )



                        let pin = MyCustomAnnotation(
                            pinTitle: "Data: " + (singleStruct.data_speed ?? "unknow") + " kBs",
                            pinSubtitle: "log type: " + (singleStruct.log_type ?? "unknow"),
                            pinLocation: locationToShow

                        )




                        self.myLocationsToUse.append(pin)

                    }
                }

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("error serializing json:\n", jsonErr)

            }

            }.resume()


    }
```

structs:

```
struct PostBlueprint: Codable {

    let rsrp : String?
    let lat : String?
    let long : String?
    let data_speed: String?
    let log_type : String?

}


class MyCustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(pinTitle : String, pinSubtitle: String, pinLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        coordinate = pinLocation
        title = pinTitle
        subtitle = pinSubtitle


    }

}
```

Comment: Try to avoid using *snake case* in Swift: `data_speed` -> `dataSpeed`. You're probably using it because of response from API. But, you can use *coding keys* for different names of properites of json and your model. Or better: in this case you can use *key decoding strategy* `convertFromSnakeCase`

Comment: thanks, I'll update it! any hint for main issue?

Comment: a notification with "test this" arrived to me, but there is no answer here...